# Hash function based cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-generator

I once read/heard that one could generate a cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator based on two cryptographically secure hash functions.

The algorithm goes this way:

- Let $f$ and $g$ be two independant cryptographically secure hash functions of block size $s$.
- This algorithm outputs blocks of $s$, the block $n$ is defined as: $output[n \times s; (n+1) \times s] = f(g_{n}(seed))$
- The function $g_{n}(seed)$ is defined as $g_{n} = g_{n-1}(seed)$ where $g_{0}(seed) = g(seed)$.

Concretely, the first block is generated with $f(g(seed))$, the second block with $f(g(g(seed)))$, then $f(g(g(g(seed))))$, and so on...

I've been looking around for any paper, or anybody mentioning this algorithm and/or trying to do cryptanalysis of this algorithm, but I haven't found anything.

[Cryptographically strong seeded pseudo random number generator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51370) suggests the same algorithm, but only uses one hash function contrary to what I'm suggesting. The selected answer says to use two hash functions, but I couldn't find more details in the literature.

Is this algorithm real? What is the name of it?

Comment: A couple of examples [Can a cryptographic hash be used as a cryptographic RNG?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25226/18298) . [Using a hash function as a random number generator](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66932/18298), [Would it be secure to generate random number using AES?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/62877/86735) Where see NIST SP 800-90 for hash (and HMAC) based RNGs

Comment: The question is what the conditions on $f$ and $g$ are. In general it's clearly false, just choose $f=g$.

Comment: @Maeher I edited the question. The condition on $f$ and $g$ is that they are unrelated/independant from each other.

Comment: If f and f are independent random functions, this shouldn't be tricky to prove. I'm not sure if there's a weaker condition that allows a proof though.